# Avoid Reliance Broadband Netconnect Plus Opens their website each time It Connects

Tags: windows, system

I am using Reliance Broadband Netconnect+ on windows 7, Need to avoid opening the reliance website each and every it connects to internet

http://www.technixupdate.com/stop-reliance-netconnect-page-from-opening-when-reliance-netconnect-broadband-data-card-connects-to-internet/

In this forum I found a solution, but the path does not exists in my pc.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7 and Reliance Net connect setup go to

`C:\Program Files\Reliance 3G` and  open `App.Config` in Notepad.

On the 10th line change `APP_HOME_PAGE = "www.google.co.in"`

This will start opening Google as your home page.